# Python create_csv error

Tags: c#, python, command-prompt

I have an error for the following when i tried to save the file into csv directly.

[image]

Code for C# program :

```
Process p5 = new Process();
p5.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", @"create_csv.py ../../database/gender/> ../genderlist.csv");

p5.Start();
```

I am using Python script called create_csv to create a csv file directly.

create_csv :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os.path

# This is a tiny script to help you creating a CSV file from a face
# database with a similar hierarchie:
#
#  philipp@mango:~/facerec/data/at$ tree
#  .
#  |-- README
#  |-- s1
#  |   |-- 1.pgm
#  |   |-- ...
#  |   |-- 10.pgm
#  |-- s2
#  |   |-- 1.pgm
#  |   |-- ...
#  |   |-- 10.pgm
#  ...
#  |-- s40
#  |   |-- 1.pgm
#  |   |-- ...
#  |   |-- 10.pgm
#

if __name__ == "__main__":

    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print "usage: create_csv <base_path>"
        sys.exit(1)

    BASE_PATH=sys.argv[1]
    SEPARATOR=";"

    label = 0
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(BASE_PATH):
        for subdirname in dirnames:
            subject_path = os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
            for filename in os.listdir(subject_path):
                abs_path = "%s/%s" % (subject_path, filename)
                print "%s%s%d" % (abs_path, SEPARATOR, label)
            label = label + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue9390) (or this [duplicate](http://bugs.python.org/issue12362) ) in how Windows handles the `.py` extension and how it is associated to the python interpreter.

The easiest solution is to change your command in the C# application to

```
p5.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", @"python create_csv.py ../../database/gender/> ../genderlist.csv");
```

Notice that I've added `python` in front of your `create_csv.py` command.

The bug report also indicates (as of July 2014) that this can't be duplicated on the newest versions of Python 2.7 - which as of this post is 2.7.8. You may wish to update.

Comment: Hi, i tried and use this but the argument is not applied , only opening the cmd.

Comment: Hi, i added a /c infront of python and it works. Thanks for the help